# Select additional column of row matched by `percentile_disc`

Tags: database, postgresql

Say, I want to select the the value of the 50th percentile of a table in Postgres, which works fine like this:

```
SELECT  percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by value) FROM foo;
```

But now,  I want to know the value of another column, say, `created_at` for the same row that was matched:

```
SELECT created_at, percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by value) FROM foo;
```

But this raises an error:
`column "foo.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

In theory, Postgres should be able to know which `created_at` I'm talking about, since, `percentile_disc` refers to one row at most. But I can't see a way to reference the value in the select query. Is it possible?

Comment: Since ```percentile_disc``` is an aggregate function, the result gets grouped. Therefore you cannot select any "ungrouped" columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the aggregate function for this directly, but perhaps in a sub select like this:

```sql
SELECT f.created, f.value
FROM foo f
WHERE value = (SELECT percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f2.value) FROM foo f2)
```